# Include HTML tag but just include list of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string text (for example in Russian) with HTML tags
I need to get all word with a JavaScript RegEx and exclude HTML tags

This is my RegEx

```
reg = /([^\r\n\t\f>< /]+(?!>))\b/g;
```

For example, in Russian, I need to keep all HTML tags in my string text but keep all work in Russian ( [\wа-я]+)

Its is possible to exclude & include some things in JavaScript RegEx?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3853934

Comment: thx but sorry if my first question was not very clear.. i try, with javascript regex to exclude AND include data in my regex.. its my initial question

Comment: I don't understand your need: what means "exclude AND include"? Could you post some example with input AND expected output?

Comment: exclude html tags from my string when i do my regex and keep only special chars ( in my example [\wа-я]+ )

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to parse HMTL with regexp. Instead, get the `innerText` property of the DOM node:

HTML:

```
<div id="myRussianText">
    Lorem <span>ipsum</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myRussianText');
var text = el.innerText; // 'Lorem ipsum'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cn0np3yf/

Comment: thx but sorry if my first question was not very clear.. i try, with javascript regex to exclude AND include data in my regex.. its my initial question

Comment: Why do you want to use regexp only? I'd suggest: 1) get the `innerText` 2) strip out what text you don't need using regexp